# C++ constructor inheritance error

Tags: c++, constructor

Why does the following code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Polygon {
  protected:
    int width, height;
    Polygon()
    {
             cout<<"Constructor with no arguments\n";
             width = 0;
             height = 0;
    }
    Polygon(int width,int height)
    {
                cout<<"Constructor with 2 arguments\n";
                this->width = width;
                this->height = height;
    }
 };

class Rectangle: public Polygon {
  public:
         Rectangle(int width,int height):Polygon(width,height){}
    int area ()
      { return width * height; }
 };

class Triangle: public Polygon {
  public:
         Trianlge(int width,int height): Polygon(width,height){}
    int area ()
      { return width * height / 2; }
  };

int main () {
  //Rectangle rect(4,4);
  //Triangle trgl(4,4);
  return 0;
}
```

result in those errors:

```
 test.cpp:34:39: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘Trianlge’ with no type [-fpermissive]
          Trianlge(int width,int height): Polygon(width,height){}
                                       ^
test.cpp: In member function ‘int Triangle::Trianlge(int, int)’:
test.cpp:34:42: error: only constructors take member initializers
          Trianlge(int width,int height): Polygon(width,height){}
                                          ^
test.cpp:34:64: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
          Trianlge(int width,int height): Polygon(width,height){}
```

It is a problem with the inheritance of constructors. I want to call the constructor of Polygon every time when creating a Rectangle or a Triangle.However, what blows my mind is that the classes `Rectangle` and `Triangle` are quite similar, and I get errors only for `Triangle` and not for `Rectangle`. Can you please explain me the reason for the errors and how can I fix it?

Comment: Spelling / Typo perhaps: `Trianlge` versus `Triangle`?

Comment: You misspelled `Triangle`.

Comment: ... And use initialisation lists as well

Comment: Ooooh, yes, indeed. I should have found that one by myself..

Comment: When using initalization lists, I get the error expression cannot be used as a function.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo here inside your `Triangle` class

```
Trianlge(int width,int height): Polygon(width,height){}
   ^
   ^
```